# How should I test for an ampersand in a string?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I set a variable depending on the specific value of a field. Inside an `<xsl:choose>`, the following code works perfectly:

```
<xsl:when test="property_type='hotel'">47</xsl:when>
```

However, I now need to check for a string such as "b&b":

```
<xsl:when test="property_type='b&b'">48</xsl:when>
```

This fails, giving:

> Error on line 42 column 72 of transform.xslt:   SXXP0003: Error
>   reported by XML parser: The reference to entity "b" must end with the
>   ';' delimiter.

I understand the error but I can't figure out how to get round it. The ampersand is present in the data xml and is valid (it is in CDATA). The error is in my xslt where it isn't valid.

Comment: Have you tried using `&amp;` instead of a bare `&`?

Comment: @Greg Ok, now I feel stupid. I did try that but still received an error. I've just realised the error is actually from the next occurrence where I DIDN'T replace it... So yes, you've found the answer, thanks!

Comment: I have posted that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand with the xml entity `&amp;`. Your code should look like this:

```
<xsl: when test="property_type='b&amp;b'">48</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:when test="property_type='b&amp;b'">48</xsl:when>
```

[answered by Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536143/how-should-i-test-for-an-ampersand-in-a-string#comment13630094_10536143)